# How to avoid IE8 trying to create a WebDAV connection for office documents in subversion?

Tags: windows-7, svn, internet-explorer

We have currently a weird problem when navigating a subversion repository on Windows 7 with Internet Explorer 8. It works like that:

- A user opens the internet explorer 8 and enters a Subversion URL to his repository (if that is relevant, it works only with `https`).
- He has to enter initially his credentials.
- He navigates through the directories, and Subversion does not ask him again his credentials.
- However, when he tries to open a file, the authentication dialog of the browser pops up, and he has to enter his user ID and password again. For each download, this happens at least 3 times, sometimes 4 times. This only happens for office documents like word, excel and powerpoint formats (`*.doc`, `*.xls`, `*.ppt`), not for other formats (`*.pdf`, `*.zip`, ...).

When we use Firefox (any version), no popup comes along, the browser only opens the dialog once and answers the request of Subversion by itself (which is what we want to reach for Internet Explorer 8 as well).

After having investigated some more time into the problem, it seems that it has something to do with what the Internet Explorer thinks he has to do with Subversion. He tries to create a WebDAV connection to the server which fails. After the three failures, the document opens read-only as usual.

What can we do to reach the same behavior for all browsers? Is there any magical setting we can set in Internet Explorer 8 to avoid the usage of WebDAV for Subversion automatically?

Comment: See:  http://serverfault.com/questions/301955/stopping-microsoft-office-2010-from-integrating-with-subversion-server-as-if-it

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is just a guess but is that what:

```
SVNAutoversioning On
```

is for?